# Start html file from pane in javafx

Tags: javafx

In my JavaFX implementation I use a pane, where I want to open a webview, when a button on the pane is clicked.

But however with this snippet it does not work:

```
    WebView webView = new WebView();

    WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();

    webEngine.load("http://google.com");

    button.setOnAction((event) -> {
        webEngine.load(url.toExternalForm());

    });
```

I've got this to call fxml:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("test.fxml")); 

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.show();
```

Any hint? thx

Comment: Did you add the `WebView` to the scene? Furthermore you can hardly call it "opening a `WebView`", if you load a page before...

Comment: I did a little change in my posting: with the fxmlloader i'm loading my fxml file and put it in the scene. there is a button in my fxml file. I want to call a website or a local html file, when it is clicked. How can I get it done? can I add webview and "root" to the same scene?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your pane to the root and add your webview to the pane. Also, look at this button handler compared to yours.

```
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");

        WebView webview = new WebView();
        WebEngine webengine = webview.getEngine();

        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                webengine.load("http://www.google.com");
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(btn, webview);//I don't see where you are doing this


        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```